# count number of occurrences within a date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

```
max_date = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
min_date = "06-08-2021"
```

I have a df that looks like this. For now it only has 1 row:

```
name       value 
Name1      23
```

Then I have another dataset `df2` that looks like this:

```
date            group 
07-08-2021      A
07-08-2021      A
06-08-2021      A
09-08-2021      A
07-08-2021      A
07-08-2021      B
06-08-2021      B
03-08-2020      A
```

I want to iterate through all rows of `df2` and if the date if within the range of `min_date` and `max_date`, I want to do a cummulative sum of all occurences of A and B.

This means that I want to count the number of times a particular group type occured within that range. Then I want to add the that value to my first dataset. Something like this:

```
name       value     count_A        count_B   
Name1      23        5              2
```

Note that the last row:

```
03-08-2020      A
```

is not counted since the date doesn't fall in the range.

EDIT:
sample df:

```
details = {
    'Name' : ['Name1'],
    'Value' : [23],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(details)

details = {
    'Date' : ['07-08-2021', '07-08-2021', '06-08-2021', '09-08-2021','07-08-2021','07-08-2021','06-08-2021','03-08-2020'],
    'Group' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A','B','B','A'],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

Comment: This is a simple filter then group by and use count 

If you can give me ways to create the df, I'll show you

Comment: edited the qs to create a sample df @KaviHarjani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
details = {
    'Date' : ['07-08-2021', '07-08-2021', '06-08-2021', '09-08-2021','07-08-2021','07-08-2021','06-08-2021','03-08-2020'],
    'Group' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A','B','B','A'],
}
details1 = {
    'Name' : ['Name1'],
    'Value' : [23],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(details1)  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
max_date = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
min_date = "06-08-2021"
df = df[(df['Date'] <= max_date) & (df['Date'] > min_date)]
df = df.groupby('Group').count()
df1_transposed = df.T
df1_transposed = df1_transposed[['A', 'B']]
df1_transposed = df1_transposed.reset_index()
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df1_transposed, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df1 = df1[['Name', 'Value', 'A', 'B']]
df1.rename(columns = {'A':'count_A', 'B':'count_B'}, inplace = True)

print(df1)
```

output

```
Name  Value  count_A  count_B
  Name1     23        4        1
```

Comment: could you also explain the transpose part?

Comment: Sure, transpose() function is used to transpose index and columns.
It changes your index with column names 
https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-transpose.php#:~:text=DataFrame%20%2D%20transpose()%20function,as%20columns%20and%20vice%2Dversa.&text=If%20True%2C%20the%20underlying%20data,copy%20is%20made%20if%20possible.

Comment: Can you take a look here too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72802030/count-becomes-zero-after-transposing-df

Answer (score 1):

Preferably work with `datetime.date` objects instead of strings:

```py
from datetime import date

max_date = date.today()
min_date = date(2021,8,6)
```

If the dates in df2 are strings, you may [convert them to `datetime.date` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/12946000) first, while iterating through all the rows:

```py
# example for first iteration of df2
from datetime import date

# iterate over all dates in your df2 and include the following:
dash_date = '07-08-2021'
py_date = datetime.strptime(dash_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()

# check if date of current iteration is between max_date and min_date
py_date > min_date and py_date < max_date
```

Based on the comparison you can decide whether you want to add the value to your first data set or not.